# How do i debug a bitcoin transaction

Tags: script, raw-transaction, transaction-verification

My main problem is understanding how to convert the response from `bitcoin-cli "decoderawtransaction"` to the script format i am supposed to put in the debugginng tool. i.e my problem is understanding how to build the bitcoin script from the decoded transaction especially when trying to spend a segwit innput

For example how do i convert something like this

```
{
"txid": "159cdd5017ff7d2c4e1d5cd37793a125b8545b9bc99eb9cbec427978d11956c7",
"hash": "311d68d33ae87866a9d1e5482b8311bd2e9f9199f652747734b2515dc43bd835",
"version": 1,
"size": 222,
"vsize": 141,
"weight": 561,
"locktime": 0,
"vin": [
    {
        "txid": "d26bb78f9fa8b1e3f0b711af2861a3e02d579be61bc6efc3a84ed7bd82589466",
        "vout": 0,
        "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "",
            "hex": ""
        },
        "txinwitness": [
            "30440220711e2049f666f750f4b1816ca32c0db56de99e5f461fd454f209dae8e274e76f02206e5870f1f52ad70674a6a810218de0c15c45b153cb8b2a0ec2dc33a3f23dc14f01",
            "030713ff1cf6035cbaf5eb4a2f27d99214b72313f47276047cee2a7da5f35693b1"
        ],
        "sequence": 4294967295
    }
],
"vout": [
    {
        "value": 0.0005,
        "n": 0,
        "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 27b107c892a49b83f76c1e6c5d5860ba36d5da7f",
            "hex": "001427b107c892a49b83f76c1e6c5d5860ba36d5da7f",
            "reqSigs": 1,
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
            "addresses": [
                "bc1qy7cs0jyj5jdc8amvrek96krqhgmdtknljra09w"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value": 0.00019448,
        "n": 1,
        "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 2d5704072aa356ee73ce7dbcdcd77a56da29661f",
            "hex": "00142d5704072aa356ee73ce7dbcdcd77a56da29661f",
            "reqSigs": 1,
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
            "addresses": [
                "bc1q94tsgpe25dtwuu7w0k7de4m62mdzjesle4zjex"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

into something like this

```
    30450221009f61f453f44e807fdc538ca21710393d34005dd5709dabd8b6b9ccf09ea0b36a0220420d91a33f43d7b979471220e12cd1025975bd2e6c0bf2a14eb65ad89d578104 
02de8f92034b9b3c956c1896d23a628537561e29faa772438aac2265c91ede6519
OP_DUP
OP_HASH160
393164d26cc8a065cb4915f46f6346d63ae26075
OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

Can someone please explain this or point me to a reading that explains this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decoding ScriptSig](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/71867/decoding-scriptsig)